# Fixed Header/Panels don't "un-fix"visually in landscape despite media query in Android

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-panel

I'm using the following media query to get rid of a fixed heard and panel in jQuery Mobile.

```
@media only screen and (orientation: landscape) {
.ui-header-fixed {
    position: absolute;
}
.ui-panel-fixed {
    position: absolute;
}
```

}

The media query works. If I'm landscape when I load the screen, the header is unfixed. However, if I go portrait (where it's fixed) then go back, the header remains fixed.

Sort of.

It's only visually fixed. The buttons aren't clickable unless you're at the top of the screen (where they would be clickable anyway). As soon as you scroll, they are untouchable.

Similar issue with the panels. The panel appears to be fixed after scrolling, but if you click a nav link, you're actually touching a different link.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Let me see your codes, meanwhile add a class to your header and try this script.

## JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".your_header").fixedtoolbar({ tapToggle: false });
});
```

Comment: Tap toggle is already disabled. What seems to be happening is the visual presence of the nav and panels are ghosts. They're not there, yet visibly, they are.

Comment: did you add your custom css? like position absolute or fixed.